# Div tag within img tag

Tags: image, dom, html

I need to add a text on each of the image and I have the image gallery constructed using img tags. Can't I append div tags under img tags. Similar to the one shown here :

```
<img id="img1" class="img1_1" src="hello1_1">
  <div class="textDesc">HELLO1_1</div>
</img>
```

Though the div is appended to img tag , but I cant see the text "HELLO1_1" on the image.

Please can anyone help me?
If you need the source code I can share it with you.

Here is the link to test the scenario :
http://jsfiddle.net/XUR5K/9/

Comment: You have to do it the other way round. Put the img inside the div tag instead.

Comment: You should describe what you wish to accomplish, instead of an assumed solution (which cannot possibly work). People have made different guesses on that in their answers. Do you wish to show a caption below (or above or aside) the image, or do you wish to put some text inside (over) the image, like a name in the map? There are mixed signals on this in your question.

Comment: Thanks Eddy. I reversed the hierarchy and it worked.

Answer (score 19):

An image tag can not have child elements. Instead, you need to position the DIV on top of the image using CSS.

Example:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <img />
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 10px;">Text</div>
</div>
```

That's but one example. There's plenty of ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your answers. I changed the hierarchy of div and img and it worked.

Comment: But if the image is centered inside the parent `div` while it doesn't hold its whole width it won't align well. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @Royi Indeed, they have options like image fit now using just CSS and you can't know the bounds of the image. If it allowed children (like a caption for example) you'd be able to align them to the resulting (from the fit operation) image bounds

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis, Could you give an example?

Comment: @Royi I mean https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp - how can you know where it fit the image exactly so that you can place say a caption under it with left-alignment to the image's edge?

Answer (score 10):

The `img` element has a self closing tag, so you can't give it child elements and expect it to work. Its content model is defined as *empty*. [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-img-element.html#the-img-element).

I suspect any children you specify won't be rendered because an `img` element is a *replaced* element, as mentioned in the W3C spec.

Answer (score -4):

Rules of good tone.

1. Use *null* source in IMG tag.
2. Use CSS *content:""* for WebKit browsers.
3. Insert element through *JavaScript*. **Clear in HTML does not affect.**

Also you can use pseudo elements.

Example: https://github.com/Alexei03a/canvas-img