# img with appendChild

Tags: image, mouseover, html, appendchild

If I surround an `img` tag with a `span` and put the `mouseover` in the `span` it works. If I don't have the `span` and just put the `mouseover` in the `img`, it doesn't (see single line of html in body).

**Can I not append a child directly to an image?**

```html
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMsg(obj) {
   var spn;
   spn = document.createElement('span');
   spn.innerHTML = "test message";
   obj.appendChild(spn);
   obj.onmouseout = function() {obj.removeChild(spn)};
 }
</script>

<body>
  <img onmouseover="showMsg(this)" src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/smiley.gif">
<!--
  <span onmouseover="showMsg(this)"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/smiley.gif"></span>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10425398/32746

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, an [`<img>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html) is a void element.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, however, is use a transparent `div` that covers the `image`and append it to that.