# Write text over div without using .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got again a rather simple question, that I couldn't find an answer to.

I was using sofar the Jquery function .text() to write text on mouseenter on a dynamically created div. I came to realise that this only worked on my Iceweasel, but not in Chrome for instance. Instead ot .text() everywhere people advised of using the .val(), but I can't seem to figure out exactly how to use it in my implementation, since the divs had no previous text value.

Please find below a simple code, with .text() to understnad the question.

```
(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = "<img width=\"" + data.size[i][0] + "\" height=\"" + data.size[i][1] + "\" id=\"" + i + "\">";
        span.style.position = "absolute";
        span.style.left = data.coords[i][0] + "px";
        span.style.top = data.coords[i][1] + "px";
        document.body.appendChild(span);
    }
}());

for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    $('#' + i).mouseenter(function() { 
         $(this).text("text");  
    });
    $('#' + i).mouseleave(function() { 
         $(this).text("") 
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ckpx6esj/1/

I hope someone can give me an idea, of how to apply .val() or use something else entirely to make this work for chrome also.

Best Regards and Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why doesnt it work when you use val()?

Comment: Doubt it's a problem with `.text()` - could be your invalid ids. `1` is not a valid id value - HTML ids must begin with an alpha character (or underscore). It's possible that Chrome et al aren't able to retrieve the element from the DOM when trying to access it by that invalid id.

Comment: It because you forgot to set id for you spans. You can not use `.text()` method on images.

Comment: ^ heh or that - the id is being set on the `<img>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleverest I could think to don't screw up your for loop is appending a `<p>` tag containing your text and removing it on mouseleave:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
                $('#' + i).on("mouseenter",function() { 
                        $(this).parent().append("<p>text</p>"); 
                    });
                $('#' + i).on("mouseleave",function() { 
                        $(this).parent().find("p").remove(); 
                });
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ckpx6esj/2/

Besides, text was not working because you are listening to the `image` (`<img>`) instead of the `span`. Images has no `.text()` prototype, hence you should access its `parent()` (which is a `<span>` in that case) if you want to use the `.text()` prototype, but using `.text()` on the parent will **remove the image**, hence the idea of appending the text and removing it later.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you put text in an image tag!

```
<img>Some text</img>
```

This is invalid HTML, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10425398/2302862).

If you want text over an image, I suggest using a `div` with `background: url(...)` instead.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckpx6esj/3/).

Answer (score 0):

According to specification, [`val()` function](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is to set value attribute and it only matters for input fields on your page. [`text()` function](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is to change content of your element.

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea.

So you should use `text()` function in your code.

Also according to your code you change text property of `<img>` element. This is not good. You should change text of your `<span>`. So just move your id to `span` element.

Comment: I am using text(), but it doesn't work on Chrome. That the whole question.

Comment: I just added answer to your whole question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the jQuery equivalent of Javascript's native `innerHtml`, go for `$(this).html('text');`.

Take a look at these functions:

http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
$(this).html('text');
```

http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
$(this).append('text'); // Note that this appends instead of replaces
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
$(this).val('text');
```

Or if you're feeling adventurous:

http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

```
$('text').appendTo($(this)); // Performance penalty for creating an object out of 'text'
```

Comment: +1 for append and html, seems to be the ones they should be using here, imo you shouldn't be using text or val on a div

Answer (score 0):

First I will use class instead id, it will save using the second loop,
also if you want to have also text and also image you can do it but it will be littel complicated I would recommand add some child element to the span that will contain the text, I didnt do it just for the challenge
http://jsfiddle.net/ckpx6esj/5/

**simple plugin to change the text without changing the html elements**

```
$.fn.selectorText = function(text) {
    var str = '';

    this.contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType === 3) {
            if(typeof(text) === 'string'){
                this.textContent = text;
                return false;
            }else{
                str += this.textContent || this.innerText || '';
            }

        }
    });

    return str;
};


var thisData = [{
    'coords' : [[100,100], [300, 300], [200, 200]],
    'size' : [[30, 30], [30, 30], [30, 30]]
}];
var data = thisData[0];

(function(){

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.setAttribute('class','spanImage');
        span.style.position = "absolute";
        span.style.left = data.coords[i][0] + "px";
        span.style.top = data.coords[i][1] + "px";
        span.innerHTML = "\n<img width=\"" + data.size[i][0] + "\" height=\"" + data.size[i][1] + "\" id=\"" + i + "\">";
        document.body.appendChild(span);
    }


$('.spanImage')
  .on( 'mouseenter', function() {
   $(this).selectorText('text');    
  })
  .on( 'mouseleave', function() {
   $(this).selectorText('');
  });
}());
```