# Text in an image

Tags: html, css, image, text

How can I get my first name and last name below to be shown within an image at the top in the middle middle (with a bit of space from the top), and to have their position remain still together with the image when rendering the browser smaller or bigger?

(I have seen this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp, but is there any other way?)

Any help welcome, please

```css
body{
background-image: url(http://www.icotoken.tel/images/slider_slide_5.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
text-align: center;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
color: white;
}

.bigger{
padding: 30px;
height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DYwc96nXkAY1xFh.jpg" class= "bigger">
<h3>First Name</h3>
<h3>Last Name</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there something in particular you don't like about the method you linked?

Comment: The texts do not remain still and even come out of the image while rendering the browser smaller

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425377/div-tag-within-img-tag) for more information.

```css
body{
background-image: url(http://www.icotoken.tel/images/slider_slide_5.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}

.container {
  position:relative;
}

.TextContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%,0);
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><img class="bigger" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DYwc96nXkAY1xFh.jpg"/>
  <div class="TextContainer">
    <h3>First Name</h3>
    <h3>Last Name</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty much, expect that I would like the First Name and Last Name at the top in the middle and to remain still with the image when rendering the browser smaller or bigger

Comment: I updated the code snippet, First Name and Last Name are at the top in the middle.

Comment: That's good. Only problem is when the browser gets smaller, the text doesn't remain still

Comment: what do you mean? can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: How do I upload a screenshot?

Comment: Copy the code on this website: https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1100, then render it smaller from right to left